# Java I/O delay creating a file in the file system

Tags: java, file, exception, io

I have legacy code which uses BufferedWriter to create a file in the file system.

The problem is that when there is some verification error in program it creates an empty file.
It should not create the file at all when there is an verification error, but the error is detected only when data is written to it (verification). PFB the example code:

```
//Legacy code
    File file1= new File(<path to directory>);
    BufferedWriter dBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1));

//Code that can have error and this repeats in loop
    String str = "some string or null if error occurs";
    if(validate(str)){  
        dBufferedWriter.write(str);
    }

//Later at end
    dBufferedWriter.close();
```

Is there a way to delay creating a file when it's not needed?

Comment: What kind of errors you want to avoid? What kind of error handling are you doing? I don't see anything here in your snippet.

Comment: Please give us a full example of what you are trying to accomplish here, also what is the writer testing ?

Comment: for example if str = "password" i would like to skip creating the file. It does not matter what rules are there over the string value, but some verification is done over string. Let me modify the code to explain it.

Comment: I would do private boolean validateContent(Object data) . IF and only IF its fine then invoke the file io part

Comment: What is `dBufferedWriter`? This code doesn't compile.

Comment: Hi @EJP , I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create new `FileWriter` it creates new file if this file does not exists. If you don't need any file in case of exception, you can use `try{...}finally{...}`:

```
File file = new File(<path to directory>);
BufferedWriter dBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
try{        
    // some code where you can get exception

    String str = "some string or null if error occurs";
    dBufferedWriter.write(str);     
}finally{
    dBufferedWriter.close();
    if(file.length()==0) file.delete();
}
```

By the way, it is a good practice to use `finally` for close resource, even if you don't need to check file length.

Sure, if you can change legacy code's order, make it so, that the file will be created after verification code. In case of exception code after verification loop will not be reached:

```
// some code where you can get exception

Writer fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(<path to directory>));
String str = "some string or null if error occurs";
dBufferedWriter.write(str);     
dBufferedWriter.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, i can delete it this way but is there any better way to do it. Like Java should write the file to file system, only at end when I know that the values are correct.

Comment: @amitmah do you need to write anything to the file in the verification loop?

Comment: No its not compulsory, i can write it after the loop is over.

Comment: @amitmah I updated answer to use `finally`. this way is more correct.

Comment: Thanks I will try this

Answer (score 1):

So the legacy code shouldn't create the file if it isn't going to be needed. So fix that.

```
String str = "some string or null if error occurs";
if(validate(str)){  
    File file1= new File(<path to directory>);
    BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1));
    dBufferedWriter.write(str);
    dBufferedWriter.close();        
}
```

... assuming `dBufferedWriter` and `writer1` are the same thing.